# unix symlink creating additional directory

Tags: unix, symlink

I am trying to create a simple symlink where /XXX/YYY points to /AAA/BBB/logs directory,
I am running this command:

```
ln -s /AAA/BBB/logs /XXX/YYY
```

But I am getting one more directory under /XXX/YYY directory called "logs" 
So my symlink is now

```
/XXX/YYY/logs -> /AAA/BBB/logs
```

whereas I need it to be

```
 /XXX/YYY -> /AAA/BBB/logs
```

but I don't need this "logs" directory to be created.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have a folder named /XXX/YYY.  So when you issue the command:

```
ln -s /AAA/BBB/logs /XXX/YYY
```

You get this:

```
/XXX/YYY/logs -> /AAA/BBB/logs
```

You need to not have the YYY folder exist.  Then the command will create the symlink named YYY that links to /AAA/BBB/logs.